# Is it possible in python to import an assigned string

Tags: python

In Python, of course you can say:

```
from file import variable
```

But is it possible to import a file at runtime when it is assigned in `__main__` ? For example, you pass a variable in a command line called the file you want to your program, call it `daily`

Can you now say,

```
from daily import dailyList
```

So daily is a string, and it is not known until the command line is parsed?

Comment: You're looking for `importlib.import_module`

Comment: you could also do `module = __import__("daily")` and then use daily list via `module.dailyList`